# sklearn ROC curver

Tags: keras, scikit-learn, roc

I have 10 classes, and my `y_test` has shape `(1000, 10)` and it looks like this:

```
array([[0, 0, 1, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       ...,
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]], dtype=int64)
```

If I use the following where `i` is the class number

```
fpr[i], tpr[i], _ = roc_curve(y_test[:, i], y_pred[:, i])
```

should `y_pred` be

```
y_pred = model.predict(x_test)

OR

y_pred = np.argmax(model.predict(x_test), axis=1)
lb = LabelBinarizer()
lb.fit(y_test)
y_pred = lb.transform(y_pred)
```

The first option gives me something like this:

```
[[6.87280996e-11 6.28617670e-07 9.96915460e-01 ... 3.08361766e-03
  3.47333212e-14 2.83545876e-09]
 [7.04240659e-30 1.51786850e-07 8.49807921e-28 ... 6.62584656e-33
  6.97696034e-19 1.01019222e-20]
 [2.97537670e-14 2.67199534e-24 2.85646610e-19 ... 2.19898160e-15
  7.03626012e-22 7.56072279e-18]
 ...
 [1.63774752e-15 1.32784101e-06 1.23182635e-05 ... 3.60217566e-14
  6.01247484e-05 2.61179358e-01]
 [2.09420733e-35 6.94865276e-10 1.14242395e-22 ... 5.08080394e-22
  1.20934697e-19 1.77760468e-17]
 [1.68334747e-13 8.53335252e-04 4.40571597e-07 ... 1.70050384e-06
  1.48684137e-06 2.93400045e-03]]
```

with shape `(1000,10)`.

where the latter option gives

```
[[0 0 1 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 ...
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]]
```

with shape `(1000,10)`

Which way is the correct approach? in other words, what would this `y_pred` be when passing to `sklearn.metrics.roc_curve()`.

Forget to mention, using the first option gives me extremely high (almost 1) AUC values for all classes, whereas the second option seems to generate reasonable AUC values.

The ROC curves using the two options are below, which one looks more correct?

[image: first option]
[image: second option]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the first option, and that's what the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_curve.html) asks for:

> **y_scorendarray of shape (n_samples,)**
>
> Target scores, can either be **probability estimates of the positive class, confidence values, or non-thresholded measure of decisions** (as returned by “decision_function” on some classifiers).

Also, the first graph looks like a ROC curve, while the second is weird.

And finally, ROC curves intend to study "different classification thresholds". That means you need predictions "as probabilities" (confidences), not as 0's and 1's.

When you take an `argmax`, you throw away the probabilities/confidences, making it impossible to study thresholds.

Comment: I've added the ROC graph, can you please tell me which one is correct?

Comment: @sensationti, the first graph looks like a ROC curve. It's a very high value indeed, but that is the shape of a ROC curve. The second is weird.